# Acecomplete doesn't show 'meta' word

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, ace-editor

I successfully connected ace-editor with autocomplete but find an annoying bug: if autocomplete line is too long, 'meta' word is not shown: [image]
How can I split my long line for multiple lines and show 'meta' word?
If it's not possilbe, how to show 'meta' word at least?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ace allows to use `caption` and `value` properties to set different texts for insertion and display

```
{
   caption // short descriptive string
   value // the long string that gets inserted
}
```

you can aslo set `item.docText` to `value`, so that the value is displayed in the tooltip when the item is selected

Comment: How I can this? Currently I have:
return { name: element.Word, word: element.Word, meta: element.Meta };

Comment: Thanks, changed to: return { caption: element.Word.slice(0, 85), word: element.Word, meta: element.Meta };